# Debugging ERROR 000732 Cannot create table from feature class in file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, table, error-000732

I am unable to create table  from feature class in file geodatabase. below is the screen of shot of the tool with error message ERROR 000732

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is complaining about a path name to the table that contains a file geodatabase name `shell_ele.gdb` twice.

It seems unlikely that you would store a file geodabase inside a file geodatabase folder so I would say that either the message that it does not exist is accurate, or if it does exist at that location then it is an unsupported pathname.